# Call to a member function getData() using facebook marketing api

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am currently testing the facebook marketing API to use it to get data from campaigns for a custom dashboard.

I am able to get data out from the ad account, but for some, for me, unknown reason a am getting `Call to a member function getData() on a non-object` while getting data. It will output some data before exiting.

I am testing with this

```
if($_SESSION["facebook_access_token"]) {

    Api::init(
        'XXXXXXXXXX',
        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        $_SESSION["facebook_access_token"]
    );

    $account = new AdAccount('act_XXXXXXXXXXXXX');

    $campaigns = $account->getCampaigns(array(
            CampaignFields::NAME,
            CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
            CampaignFields::EFFECTIVE_STATUS,
            CampaignFields::CONFIGURED_STATUS
    ), array(
        CampaignFields::EFFECTIVE_STATUS => array(
            ArchivableCrudObjectEffectiveStatuses::ACTIVE
        ),
    ));

    foreach($campaigns as $campaignset) {

        $cid = $campaignset->getData()['id'];

        $campaign = new Campaign($cid);

        $insights = $campaign->getInsights(array(
           InsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME,
           InsightsFields::ADSET_NAME
        ));

        var_dump($insights->current()->getData());

    }


}
```

It will output this

```
array (size=48)
  'account_id' => null
  'account_name' => null
  'action_values' => null
  'actions' => null
  'actions_per_impression' => null
  'ad_id' => null
  'ad_name' => null
  'adset_id' => null
  'adset_name' => null
  'call_to_action_clicks' => null
  'campaign_id' => null
  'campaign_name' => string 'Svendborg - MÃ¸dsparnord â€“ kopi' (length=33)
  'cost_per_action_type' => null
  'cost_per_total_action' => null
  'cost_per_unique_click' => null
  'cost_per_inline_link_click' => null
  'cost_per_inline_post_engagement' => null
  'cpm' => null
  'cpp' => null
  'ctr' => null
  'date_start' => string '2015-11-05' (length=10)
  'date_stop' => string '2015-12-07' (length=10)
  'frequency' => null
  'impressions' => null
  'inline_link_clicks' => null
  'inline_post_engagement' => null
  'product_id' => null
  'reach' => null
  'relevance_score' => null
  'social_clicks' => null
  'social_impressions' => null
  'social_reach' => null
  'spend' => null
  'total_action_value' => null
  'total_actions' => null
  'total_unique_actions' => null
  'unique_clicks' => null
  'unique_ctr' => null
  'unique_social_clicks' => null
  'video_avg_pct_watched_actions' => null
  'video_avg_sec_watched_actions' => null
  'video_complete_watched_actions' => null
  'video_p100_watched_actions' => null
  'video_p25_watched_actions' => null
  'video_p50_watched_actions' => null
  'video_p75_watched_actions' => null
  'video_p95_watched_actions' => null
  'website_ctr' => null
```

and some other campaigns, but it will always stop with the above mentioned error at the same spot every time. But I cannot see what's wrong.

Comment: Probably do with one of the campaigns. I tried to repro the error but it works fine for me.

Comment: I'd try and figure out what exactly is in $campaigns when the error happens. Is $campaignset null, an array, an empty array etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because one of our campaign does not have insights data on your query. You could handle that as exception in the loop.

However, I want to promote a best practice for this. In your use case, you should really use the level parameter from the ad account, unless you have hundreds campaigns under that account.

```
$adAccount = new AdAccount('<AD_CAMPAIGN_ID>');
$params = array(
  'level' => AdsInsightsLevelValues::Campaign,
  'date_preset' => InsightsPresets::LAST_7_DAYS,
);
$insights = $adAccount->getInsights(null, $params);
print_r($insights);
```

This way you don't even need a for loop.

And we also have a tool to guide you generate code in the Getting Started session in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[app_id]/marketing-api/
Basically you can pick metrics and the wizard will generate a working code for you. (It is only generating Java code for now, but code pattern is the same)